# PHP memory_limit local value does not match php.ini value

Tags: php, virtualhost, memory, httpd.conf, php.ini

CentOS system.

Summary: changed memory_limit in master and local php.ini and yet no change in the local value for a particular virtual host.

Trying to improve performance, I set the memory_limit to 1024M in /etc/php.ini

phpinfo() shows Master and Local values for other virtual hosts on the server as 1024M. Changing the value in /etc/php.ini changes all values, except one.

One site is stuck with a local value of 256M.

I thought I found the problem: there is a php.ini file (which I didn't know about) in that site's root, and it had

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

I changed it to 1024M. Problem solved? No. And now I don't know where to look. Obviously, I've restarted apache (/etc/init.d/httpd restart), and that usually does the trick.

I also turned off APC cache, though I don't think it would cache ini files.

And finally, I tried adding this to the virtual host in httpd.conf:

```
php_value memory_limit 536870912
```

(yes, that would be 512MB)
And that had no effect whatsoever.

What else could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. There was a hidden .htaccess file in the site root that was overriding all other values.

It had the line:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

I changed it to:

```
php_value memory_limit 1024M
```

No need to restart apache, the memory limit went up to 1024M immediately.

——————

Also, if you load a `phpinfo()` page in your website root, near the top you can see configuration files affecting PHP. Search “config” and you’ll find a list.

Comment: For me there is also such a file, but it is set to 5G and it still shows 756M. I grepped the whole folder after `php_value memory_limit` and changed everthing It found to 5G but does not change anything

Comment: @Black can you load your `phpinfo()`  page or run it in console and see which configuration files are affecting your setup? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: I figured it out, there were two .user.ini somewhere in the project. One in the root and one in pub folder. There the value was overriden.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that there can be another hidden file named `.user.ini` which can set php variables like `php.ini`.

The value in `.user.ini` was showing as Local Value even though I tried setting the value in `php.ini`. Here the value set using `php.ini` was updating the Global Value only and not the Local Value. Changing the value in `.user.ini` updated Local Value.

This was my issue and it took me hours to identify this. May save some time for some. :)

Answer (score 0):

As another user pointed out, there is also a `.user.ini` which can change the value.
CD to your root directory of the project where your phpinfo.php is located.

Execute `find -type f -name "*.user.ini"`

In my case I got:

```
./pub/.user.ini
./.user.ini
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/pub/.user.ini
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/.user.ini
```

So I opened `./.user.ini` and `./pub/.user.ini` and changed the value of `memory_limit` accordingly. Now check if the local value in your phpinfo has changed.

If not then you need to search the whole project with:

```
grep -iR memory_limit
```

And change all occurences.